# How can I stop my records from overwriting when i close the program and run it again in c++

Tags: c++

am trying to save some user input to a dat file and when the program is closed and open again i would like to save new records onto the ones i have already gotten.. and i am not sure what the latest commands are to read the data back and display on the screen ive read books but they all have old command that doesn't work.

```
//account.h
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <String>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std; 
struct Account
{
public :
void login();
void userRegister();
protected :
int username;
int password;

};


void Account :: userRegister()
{
Account myAccount;
char terminator;
int myUserID = 0;
int myPassword = 0;
 std::cout << "Enter Your 8 digit UserID";
cin >>myUserID  ;
        cout << "Enter Your 6 digit password";
cin >> myPassword ;
FILE * dat = fopen("Accounts.dat", "wb");

myAccount.userID ;

myAccount.password ;
fwrite(&myAccount, sizeof(myAccount), 1, dat);
        //cin.get (terminator);
        fclose (dat);


  }
```

Comment: Call [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) with `"a+b"` to open an existing file and write to the end of it

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in append mode.

Here the `a` tells to append and the `+` to create the file if it doesn't exist.

```
FILE * dat = fopen("Accounts.dat", "ab+");
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are asking how to add new data to the existing file. To do that you need to open the file in append mode.

Change

```
FILE * dat = fopen("Accounts.dat", "wb");
```

to

```
FILE * dat = fopen("Accounts.dat", "ba+");
```